# sqlite store unique items only

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite

I would like to configure my SQLite database to not be able to store duplicates of image
in the images table for a user.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
CREATE TABLE accounts (user VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, password VARCHAR, ts TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE images (user VARCHAR, image VARCHAR, FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES accounts(user));
```

I've been looking for an option to do this without checking if the item already exists
but haven't found one yet.

For example, I currently see duplicates with item1. I would like there to be item1 and item2.

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM images;
jon|item1
jon|item1
jon|item2
```

I insert the value into the database from a shell script that calls sqlite.

```
...
sqlite3 "$DB" "INSERT INTO images(user, image) values ('$USERNAME', '$ITEM');"
```

Any help is appreciated, this is my first database project.

Comment: Gordon has the correct answer, you need to create a unique index on those fields.  Use `create unique index...` -- that should prevent duplicate entries from being created for a distinct user and image combination.  And yes, it goes after the table creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want duplicates, then create a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_images_user_image on images(user, image);
```

This will prevent duplicates from being inserted.

Comment: Would this go after the line CREATE TABLE images..?

Comment: @sgeddes . . . Yes.  Not only in the text, but in the command too.

Comment: @jonschipp . . . You would run this after the `create table`.

Answer (score 3):

(There's more wrong with this table than you think--missing `not null` constraints, missing `primary key` constraint . . .)

I'm guessing that you want only one image per user. I could be wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE images (
  user VARCHAR not null, 
  image VARCHAR not null unique, 
  primary key (user),
  FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES accounts(user)
);
```

For multiple images per user, with each image being a unique value, just change the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE images (
  user VARCHAR not null, 
  image VARCHAR not null, 
  primary key (image),
  FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES accounts(user)
);
```

Comment: Edited question. There will be more than one image per user but I would like each image to be a unique value. item1, item2, item3 is what I need but not item1, item1, item2, item2, etc.

Comment: Then you just need a different primary key.